# Split number and get element that start from specific numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following row in `Excel`. I need to split it get only the phone number that contains '+357 99' or '+357 97'

```
Phone number
+357 22333333, +357 22444444
+357 97222222
+357 22000000, +357 22111111, +357 99000000
```

For example the new resulted row should be the following:

```
Phone number

+357 97222222
+357 99000000
```

Currently I only have `=SPLIT(B2,",")`.

Can you help me please?

Comment: What happens in the output should a given row have more than one match, or would that never be expected?

Comment: Are all numbers followed by a comma? As the 3rd and 4th are not. If the data is consistent, then you could use find() and iferror()...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenThis may happen. I will need to have both.

Comment: @SolarMike Only if more that one number is available then the comma is being there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it would be possible to have more than a single match, you may try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '+357 99') or starts-with(., '+357 97')]"),""))
```

If you don't want to use `TEXTJOIN()` but you need to split the results, you could try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '+357 99') or starts-with(., '+357 97')]"),""))
```

If you don't have Excel O365, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A2,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '+357 99') or starts-with(., '+357 97')]"),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

Drag left and right.

Note `FILTERXML()` is available from Excel 2013 onwards.

If only a single value of both excists, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65489277/9758194) will handle just fine. Also, unfortunately "SPLIT()" is not an Excel function, but if you are interested in how `FILTERXML()` can be used to split a string, you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below formulas to find the numbers

for +357 97 (Enter this formula in B2 Cell)

```
=IFERROR(MID(A2,SEARCH("+357 97",A2),13),"")
```

for +357 99 (Enter this formula in C2 Cell)

```
=IFERROR(MID(A2,SEARCH("+357 99",A2),13),"")
```

Excel Snip

[image: Output Excel]

Drag the formula to the bottom cell to get all results. you can also concatenate the results to one column if you want

Answer (score 1):

I think `FILTERXML()` will best fit in this case. Use start-with in `xPath` parameter of `FilterXML()` function.

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '+357 99') or starts-with(., '+357 97')]"),"No Match")
```

[image]

An excellent explanation of `FILTERXML()` function in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) from JvdD